# Do you need to use tar before using xz/gz when distributing software?

Tags: gzip, tar, xz

Most software, when not in a package such as `.deb`, comes in `.tar.gz` or `.tar.xz`. Is it necessary to use `tar` before using `xz` or `gz`? What are the advantages of doing that?

Comment: Do you know what `tar`, `gz` and `xz` is?

Comment: Yes. `tar` is an archive with no compression (Tape ARchive), and `gz` and `xz` are archives with compression.

Comment: `gz` and `xz` are not archives, they are _just_ compression. Combine tar and gz and you get an compressed archive.

Comment: They can only store one file? When compressing something like a log file you don't need to use tar.

Comment: They don't _store_ anything, they just compress a stream of bytes.

Comment: That means they automatically use tar when you provide a file in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine several files - use `tar` and then, optionally, compress your `tar` archive with gzip or another tool. If you have 1 file only - using `tar` is meaningless, just compress the file with gzip